# ASPNET testing REST app on localhost not sending JSON message body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, networking

I have a public-facing gateway application I am trying to test by running it, and the microservice it redirects to, locally. Both are written in C# using ASPNET core functionality.

Unfortunately it seems that the POST requests sent over loopback do not at all send the JSON body, rendering it nearly impossible to test. Even running the python equivalent of netcat will give me the headers and then hang forever on the message body.

Asking the locally running gateway to interact with the cloud-based test version of the internal microservice, it behaves exactly like you would expect: sends the JSON, recieves a reply, all flawlessly.

So to recap, I have an App that can send REST calls *except* to 127.0.0.1. Where do I even start figuring out what is wrong?

Comment: you have a api getway and want to test api rest in api getway?you use postman to test and event log?